# cvxpy: map in objective function

Tags: python, optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I have a list beta_list, where each entry in the list is a vector. I want to minimize the following function

```
def two_norm(this_beta, beta):
  cp.Pnorm(beta - this_beta, p = 2)**2

def obj_fn(beta_list, beta):
  sum(map(two_norm, beta_list, itertools.repeat(beta, len(beta_list))))
```

Can cvxpy handle objective function of this form, where a function is applied to a list using `map` in python?

Comment: Have you tried it out? You're more likely to get answers if you show an error or a complete example.

Comment: actually it did work. I also heard back from the author on google mailing list, confirming as long as it is a cvxpy expression, and don't pass in a function handle - it should be fine